# Joining Shorter Length Numpy Array to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 506 rows. I have a numpy array with 501 elements that are calculated from the dataframe.

I would like to join the numpy array to the dataframe, keeping the index of the dataframe and starting the index of the numpy array with the first index value of the dataframe.

The problem is that because the numpy array has a different length and no notion of row indexes, the join operation fails.

Is there a clever way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd construct a `Series` from the np array, and then construct a new `Series` but pass the target df's index, this effectively reindexes the existing `Series`, introducing `NaN` values where there are no row values, this will align correctly against the target df:

```
In [51]:    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
s = pd.Series(np.arange(3))
s1 = pd.Series(s, index=df.index)
s1

Out[51]:
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
dtype: float64

In [53]:
df['d'] = s1
df

Out[53]:
          a         b         c    d
0  0.990381  2.583867  0.018435  0.0
1  0.867695 -0.958220 -0.351783  1.0
2  0.476210 -1.015887  1.285303  2.0
3 -0.198863 -2.514740  1.228772  NaN
```